# custom shape image container

Tags: css, html

Is there any way to have a custom-shape image container? To use something instead of `<div />`?

The problem appears when I need to add corners on top of the #content-box ( http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/8343/screenshot20111027at163.png ). The corner-images are using only half of the block element, the rest (the pink alpha-background) are blocking the active-elements underneath it.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Could you use `z-index` (CSS) to position those elements "behind" the clickable elements?

Comment: I could, but that's not what the question is asking. I want the image part (the triangle) to cover the active elements, but I don't want the rest of the `<div />` blocking the active elements.

Comment: You'll need to use a combination of a client-side imagemap and some JavaScript. I can't give you any actual code unless you give us some of yours.

Comment: hm. How can imagemap help here? Image map could only activate certain bits of `<img />`. I don't think that's an option, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own questions:

It is not possible to have a custom shape HTML element without parent block element holding it anyway, e.g. in case of SVG.

However, the one workaround that I've managed to come across is magic CSS `pointer-events` rule, which, as you might have guessed already, helps to click through the element.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

That did solve my issue.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to have custom shaped containers. You could do this though using `<div>` wrappers, each containing a different background image. For example:

html

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="content-box">
    <!-- Upload photo content box --->
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#content-wrapper,
#content-box{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}

#content-wrapper{background:url('images/four-corners.png') no-repeat}
#content-box{background:url('images/octagon.png') no-repeat}
```

This way the images won't block any active elements on the page.

Comment: Yes, though the corners have to be on top of the content, not underneath it.